# Passing ID in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a SQL where I need to get the ID from one table and query that ID with a different table where the table name is dependent on the ID(X) (CONU_X) and get the results.

Query 1

```
select NAME, ID FROM [DB].[TABLE1].[COND]
WHERE STATUS in ('STARTED','STOPPED')


NAME, ID
DB1,  1
DB2,  2
DB3,  3
```

Query 2

Need to pass ID from 1st Table to 2nd Table (CONU_X) where X is ID from Table 1.

```
Select USER from [DB].[TABLE2].[CONU_X]
or
Select USER from [DB].[TABLE2].[CONU_1] where X is ID from Table 1

USER
A
B
C
```

Desired Output

```
NAME, ID, USER
DB1,  1,   A
DB1,  1,   B
DB1,  1,   C
```

The challenge is the second table name will change based on the ID received from the first table. I have 30 id's from the first table, so I need to query corresponding 30 tables for the second query.

select INS.NAME, INS.ID, USR.USER FROM [DB].[TABLE1].[COND] INS, [DB].[TABLE2].[CONU_11] USR WHERE INS.STATUS in ('STARTED','STOPPED') AND INS.ID =11

This Works for 1 ID, I need to have my SQL read 30 ID's from TABLE1

Thank you

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Wait a minute, are you sure about Oracle? Those square brackets look more like MS SQL Server, Sybase or perhaps MS Access.

Comment: Sorry, my bad this is SQL Server.

Comment: How many CONU tables are involved?  If there are not too many you could use a conditional join, if there are too many for that to be feasible you will probably need to use a dynamic sql query.

Comment: sorry, I am not going to solve it but as you have said any help this will help you for sure. In most of the commercial databases there is a database with the scheme, so, if you have 35 tables in total , 30 of those meet a condition you can query the schema table, get the table name and query it

Comment: There are 30 tables involved (secondary) and the primary Table which has the ID. There is no Join since the second table (dynamic) has no columns to relate with the primary table. Only the Table name has ID which relates to the first table. Not sure if this is possible.

Comment: select INS.NAME, INS.ID, USR.USER 
FROM [DB].[TABLE1].[COND] INS, [DB].[TABLE2].[CONU_11] USR
WHERE INS.STATUS in ('STARTED','STOPPED')
AND INS.ID =11    This Works for 1 ID, I need to have my SQL read 30 ID's from TABLE1.

Answer (score 1):

Use `join`:

```
Select t2.USER, t1.name, t1.id
from [DB].[TABLE2].[CONU_X] x
inner join [DB].[TABLE1].[COND] c
     on x.id = c.id   -- JOIN conditions are not clear so this is a guess
where c.STATUS in ('STARTED', 'STOPPED');
```

Comment: The CONU_X table is CONU_ID where ID is from first table. Table Name will change based on the ID.

Comment: There is no Join since the second table (dynamic) has no columns to relate with the primary table. Only the Table name has ID which relates to the first table.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work but its ugly.  There may be some syntax errors but I don't have sample data to test against.  This should at least get you started.

```
DECLARE @Iteration INT
DECLARE @Sql Varchar(8000)
SET @Iteration = 1

WHILE @Iteration <= 31
BEGIN
    
SET @Sql = 'select NAME, ID 
FROM [DB].[TABLE1].[COND] Cond
Join [DB].[TABLE2].[CONU_' + @Iteration + '] Conu On Cond.ID = Conu.ID
WHERE STATUS in (''STARTED'',''STOPPED'')'
If @Iteration < 30
Begin
   SET @Sql = @Sql + 'Union All '
End
END

Execute @Sql
```

Comment: Hi Joe, the ID's are not sequential and they are random which is defined in Table 1. There are 30 ID's or 30 secondary tables need to query.